# dc.js render labels with thousand seperator

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have few bar charts in my dashboard where i'm displaying labels on top of the bar. 
My users requesting to have thousand seperators for the labels. 

The reason is the numbers are like over 7 digits and more for each bar.

Is there any workaround to achieve this functionality?

 Here is my code:

```
Chart
  .width(1700)
  .height(200) 
  .margins({top: 5, left: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30})
  .transitionDuration(1000)
  .dimension(dateDim)
  //.formatNumber(d3.format(","))
  .group(dateGroup)
  .renderLabel(true)
  .brushOn(true)
  .elasticY(true)
  //.centerBar(true)
  //.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate])) 
  .yAxisLabel("Trades per day")
  .xAxisLabel("Days")
  .ordinalColors(['#215979'])
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, d3.time.day.offset(maxDate, 1)]))
  .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('s'));
Chart.xUnits(function(){return 30;});
Chart
        .on("postRedraw", function(chart, filter){
          window.globalActiveFilters.SelectedTradeCount=chart.filters().join(",")
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The labels on top of the bars are controlled by [.label()](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#label__anchor).

In the case of bar charts, the default behavior is overridden to use the total Y value of the stacked bar:

```
_chart.label(function (d) {
    return dc.utils.printSingleValue(d.y0 + d.y);
}, false);
```

[(source link)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/bar-chart.js#L55-L57)

You can specify your own label accessor which uses `d3.format` as suggested by @REEE, supplying it the total stacked value:

```
.label(d => d3.format(',')(d.y0 + d.y1))
```

[image: stacked with comma'd labels]

[Example fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ud1spw9e/5/)

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i tried the method @REEE suggested but it throws NaN value on top of the bar.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised by that too, until I remembered that there is special processing for bar charts because of the stacking. That's why the code above uses `.y0` and `.y1` instead of `.value` as would be normal.

Comment: So which means, should i consider like thousand seperator is not achievable at present for the bar chart labels.

Comment: Huh? I wouldn't have written an answer if I didn't think it was an answer. I tested it with [the stacked bar example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) and it works for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, actually it works if i just mention d.y0 + d.y. So here is what i did chart.label(d => d3.format(',')(d.y0 + d.y)). I'll accept this as answer for my problem.

Comment: Right, as I showed above. I added a demo fiddle. It's messy but I can't think of another way to do it, given the way stacked bar charts work.

Answer (score 2):

Use d3-format, you can find the relevant docs here: https://github.com/d3/d3-format

Example use case (as shown in link above):

```
d3.format(",")(20000)
-> "20,000"
d3.format(",")(200000000)
-> "200,000,000"
```

Comment: I'm sure we can use this and achieve. I have used for my other graphs such as number display. But my ask is to display the thousand seperator for the labels which i'm displaying on top of each bar. Here is my code :        barChart
  .width(1700)
  .height(200) 
  .margins({top: 5, left: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30})
  .transitionDuration(1000)
  .dimension(dateDim)
  .formatNumber(d3.format(","))
  .group(dateGroup)
  .renderLabel(true)
  .brushOn(true)
  .elasticY(true)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full code for generating the labels please?